# Cycles baking creates odd grey lines

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texture-baking

I am trying to bake an internal scene in Blender Cycles. However, it adds some odd grey lines on top of the resulting bake:
[image: Various odd grey lines in the baked texture have been circled.]
Increasing the amount of samples does not help. You can pick up the .blend here: http://www.pasteall.org/blend/34703 (Unfortunately, my current UVs did not pack correctly, so re-baking will be required. Just select the room or the archway and click 'bake' in the bottom-right corner.)

Comment: Oh whoops, I forgot to turn off the 'only rendered' thing. It's a checkbox in the panel that opens when you press 'n'.

Comment: So is your problem solved?

Comment: No, I was just mentioning that to anyone who picked up the .blend. It makes quite a few things invisible, so it might be confusing.